# Looping an SVG slide animation off screen without overflow

Tags: css, animation, svg, overflow

How do I stop the second absolutely positioned SVG from overflowing? If impossible what are some other ways I could implement this?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/art7bx2v/2/

```
Pseudo code of structure:

container
  svg 1
  svg 1 alt
container

  .svg-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-odd {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide 15s linear 0s infinite;
}

.svg-odd-alt {
  transform: translateX(-101%);
  animation: slideAlt 15s linear 0s infinite;
}

.svg-odd, .svg-odd-alt {
  width: 3840px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideAlt {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-101%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.svg-container`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uszq6ky4/

The reason this works is because your two child elements have `position: absolute`. When you apply `position: absolute` (or `fixed`), the elements will be positioned relative to a positioned parent (other than `static`, which is the default).